# The most percentage?

Tags: word-choice, ielts

[image]

*The pie graph shows how the price of every course should be shared, measured in percentages. Overall the numbers are not that different for each part. Individual has* **the most percentage** *at 40%, followed by employer at 35%, and taxpayer has* **the least percentage** *at 25%.*

Although I know we usually use **high/low** with percentages, I'm still curious whether **more/less** with percentages are also acceptable?

Comment: No, "most percentage" is not commonly used https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+higher+percentage%2Cthe+most+percentage&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20higher%20percentage%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20most%20percentage%3B%2Cc0

Comment: In the given context, *most-least* seems more appropriate, though.

Comment: You mean we do say, a has more percentage than b, but don't say, a has the most percentage, right? @Kris

Comment: @Kris Are you there?

Comment: As a native BrE speaker, I'd use "biggest percentage" and "smallest percentage".

Comment: I would recommend *highest* and *lowest* percentage in this case.

Comment: I would probably say "the greatest percentage".

Comment: The problem is that percentage is a measure like a degree. You don't have more degree or degrees -- you have a *different* degree of some quality. Same with temperature, a fever is not more temperature, but higher temperature.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by user240918, "most percentage" is not common, but I was surprised to see that there were any hits at all for "most percentage" or "least percentage" on an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20most%20percentage%2C%20the%20least%20percentage&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20most%20percentage%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20least%20percentage%3B%2Cc0). There are a few legitimate examples, where the author wrote a sentence including "most percentage" like in this [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=oznPAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA1538&lpg=PA1538&dq=%22The%20most%20percentage%22&source=bl&ots=JXghzwE0bm&sig=ByOHNOadcLlwvYM9XEGZpaZnOA4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO47fa8NfeAhULn-AKHSjkDMkQ6AEwB3oECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22The%20most%20percentage%22&f=false), but from what I can tell, the majority of that minuscule number of hits comes from books like [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=Iux07CCye5QC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=%22The%20most%20percentage%22&source=bl&ots=zq2ddikDAG&sig=wQ4sCkyacHPs-kYzkhh7FO45qI8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO47fa8NfeAhULn-AKHSjkDMkQ6AEwCHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22The%20most%20percentage%22&f=false), where the words appear together my a matter of coincidence. While there are still very few instances of "least percentage," there are many more, like [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=tXpdDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=%22least%20percentage%22&source=bl&ots=cWz22Y94mF&sig=71kFD8IZZOqDcMAg5hkTvsCcfUo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiej5C_8tfeAhWGIMAKHX5WC5kQ6AEwCXoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22least%20percentage%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=EarRDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=%22least%20percentage%22&source=bl&ots=KM2W0XRqN4&sig=iMIQDnNFxzcJW0H7lgOCsIwZ3-c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiej5C_8tfeAhWGIMAKHX5WC5kQ6AEwC3oECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22least%20percentage%22&f=false), and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=xMASogAM5qgC&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=%22least%20percentage%22&source=bl&ots=cN1ekEn5ff&sig=Ssgq5L4jLFU0qRwaJHwaTmIhGLk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiej5C_8tfeAhWGIMAKHX5WC5kQ6AEwD3oECBMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22least%20percentage%22&f=false). I hesitate to say most and least percentage are  100% wrong since they are attested and they may be acceptable among some groups, but they certainly sound wrong to my ear.

Comment: Does it really sound wrong to your ears in any circumstances? Just wanna make sure  to never  use it again.

Comment: I can't think of any instances were I would ever use either, and I would not recommend using it. I really don't know what to think about it though, because those uses of "least percentage" were in books that I would assume were edited before publishing for grammar/style/etc. I don't know if it's a dialectical usage that I haven't heard before or a  mistake.

Comment: The reason should be  it was written by non-native speaker for educational purposes in universities I guess.

Answer (score 0):

"The pie graph shows how the price of every course should be shared, measured in percentages. Overall the numbers are not that different for each part. Individual has the most percentage at 40%, followed by employer at 35%, and taxpayer has the least percentage at 25%."

This sentence is poorly written. "Most percentage" should be "largest share".